# How do I install an old version of Postgres using APT?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, apt

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04LTS.  I'd like to install Postgres 9.3 (current version is 9.5, which is what's in the main repo).

.deb files for version 9.3 are available at http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postgresql-9.3, but I'd like to go through APT if at all possible.  I've tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql=9.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '9.3' for 'postgresql' was not found
```

(same with `postgresql=9.3.11-0ubuntu0.14.04`) and

```
$ sudo apt-get -t=14.04 install postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value '14.04' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

(since 9.3 was the most up-to-date version in the 14.04 repos).

I've looked for information on those error messages, but I can't find anything that helps.  How do I install an old version of Postgres using APT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing an older version of PostgreSQL on a newer Ubuntu system is possible, but not supported by packages supplied by Ubuntu. The same goes for a newer PostgreSQL on an older Ubuntu.

The simplest solution to use any version is to switch to the [PGDG APT](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) repository, maintained by the PostgreSQL developement group, for your PostgreSQL packages.

Beware not to mix contents between the Ubuntu and PGDG repositories, as packages share the same names. Typically you want to first purge the installed `postgresql*` and `libpq*` packages to facilitate a clean and complete switch.